# How to optimize RTMP AAC transcoding with (or without) FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, http-live-streaming, aac

I do use NginxRTMP to generate HLS. 
Problem is that HLS has not sound (since it needs AAC)

I try to trancode my RTMP sound to AAC sound with FFMPEG

```
exec_push ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/src/$name -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -vprofile baseline -preset ultrafast -s 800x600  -acodec libfaac -ar 44100  -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name
```

Problem: it takes 25% of CPU per stream.

Any idea on how to optimize that ?

Comment: You're transcoding the video as well. Did you want to?

Comment: I have RTMP with speex codec and I want to relay that to RTMP with AAC !

Comment: I used -c copy and... CPU is now 3% : great suggestion !

Comment: @yarek `-c copy` copies everything and `libfaac` is deprecated. You can do `-c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac ...` assuming you installed the lib.